# Forcing secure cookies to send with non-secure requests

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I want to send secure cookies with non-secure http requests by adding cookie headers. For this purpose, I am using code like the following to add cookie headers. When I check the header using sniffer like **Fiddler**, http request headers do not include secure cookies. Assuming there are secure cookies in the store, is this code correct or is there any other better way to do it?

Thank you,

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
        chrome.cookies.getAll({'domain': ".example.com", 'secure': true}, function (cookies) { 
           cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
                details.requestHeaders.push({name:"Cookie",value: cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value});
            });                   
        });

    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};

  }, {urls: ['http://*/*']}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: The problem is that `chrome.cookies.getAll` is asynchronous, and its callback does not run until *after* the `onBeforeSendHeaders` callback completes. I'm not sure how to solve the problem, though.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of [HTTPS Everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp). This Chrome extension does exactly the opposite of what you want, namely forcing the "secure" flag to be set on cookies. The method used to achieve this can be used for your case though. PS. You can easily view the extension's source code using the [CRX Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin)

Answer (score 0):

the solution I am about to take, is to manually get/set the request/response headers for cookie data.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it will work but you could listen for chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest even and start query cookies here. Perhaps at time of onBeforeSendHeaders call they will be ready. Or you could precache necessary cookies for domains from already opened tabs

Comment: not a safe solution, there is no guarantee that the call will be complete by the time you come to use the value